# Non-Domian Windows DNS Servers communication ports

Tags: windows, firewall, dns-hosting

Our public DNS is hosted on Non-Domain-Joined Windows servers.

Internally we have NS1 that is read/write where we manage our DNS.
Externally we have NS2 that is in the DMZ and is a read only copy of NS1.

Right now the firewall between NS1 and NS2 is wide open. I want to close it down to only what is required.

I have not been able to find what ports are used when NS1 copies the DNS data to NS2.

Is it just port 53?
Are there others required for authentication between the Primary and the read only server?

Thank you

Comment: UDP/TCP Port 53 is all you should need.